# iPhone QR code customize

Tags: ios, iphone, qr-code

I want to use customize QR,  I have a url, if I pass that url in browser they display a QR in browser and if i use this url in our code they return null, this is my url that I want to use in our code:

http://api.qrcode.unitag.fr/api?t_pwd=degraded&setting={"EYES":{"EYE_TYPE":"LLLeft","COLOR_EHD":"8a9935","COLOR_IHD":"8a9935","COLOR_EBG":"71801f","COLOR_IBG":"71801f"},"BODY_TYPE":2,"LAYOUT":{"COLORBG":"ffffff","GRADIENT_TYPE":"HORI","COLOR1":"afc928","COLOR2":"d7eb67","FORCE_SHADOW":"L","COLOR_SHADOW":"b6b8a7"}}&data={"DATA":{"MESSAGE":"Hello","PHONE":"0505050505"},"TYPE":"smsto"}

This is my code for encode that url

```
NSString *unescaped = @"http://api.qrcode.unitag.fr/api?t_pwd=degraded&setting={%22EYES%22:{%22EYE_TYPE%22:%22LLLeft%22,%22COLOR_EHD%22:%228a9935%22,%22COLOR_IHD%22:%228a9935%22,%22COLOR_EBG%22:%2271801f%22,%22COLOR_IBG%22:%2271801f%22},%22BODY_TYPE%22:2,%22LAYOUT%22:{%22COLORBG%22:%22ffffff%22,%22GRADIENT_TYPE%22:%22HORI%22,%22COLOR1%22:%22afc928%22,%22COLOR2%22:%22d7eb67%22,%22FORCE_SHADOW%22:%22L%22,%22COLOR_SHADOW%22:%22b6b8a7%22}}&data={%22DATA%22:{%22MESSAGE%22:%22Hello%22,%22PHONE%22:%220505050505%22},%22TYPE%22:%22smsto%22}";


 NSString *escapedString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
 NSLog(@"escapedString: %@", escapedString);

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
 [img_barcode setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
```

i am using above code but i am not getting image, please tell me about this process how i can get image successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your code is already escaped. By escaping it again, you destroy it.

Either start with a properly URL escaped string and don't do any further processing on it:

```
NSString *escaped = @"http://api.qrcode.unitag.fr/api?t_pwd=degraded&setting={%22EYES%22{%22EYE_TYPE%22:%22LLLeft%22,%22COLOR_EHD%22:%228a9935%22,%22COLOR_IHD%22:%228a9935%22,%22COLOR_EBG%22:%2271801f%22,%22COLOR_IBG%22:%2271801f%22},%22BODY_TYPE%22:2,%22LAYOUT%22{%22COLORBG%22:%22ffffff%22,%22GRADIENT_TYPE%22:%22HORI%22,%22COLOR1%22:%22afc928%22,%22COLOR2%22:%22d7eb67%22,%22FORCE_SHADOW%22:%22L%22,%22COLOR_SHADOW%22:%22b6b8a7%22}}&data={%22DATA%22{%22MESSAGE%22:%22Hello%22,%22PHONE%22:%220505050505%22},%22TYPE%22:%22smsto%22}";
```

Or start with the base url and the parameters, then URL escape each parameter value and combine it into the complete URL:

- Base URL: `http://api.qrcode.unitag.fr/api`
- *t_pwd*: degraded
- *setting*: `{"EYES":{"EYE_TYPE":"LLLeft","COLOR_EHD":"8a9935","COLOR_IHD":"8a9935","COLOR_EBG":"71801f","COLOR_IBG":"71801f"},"BODY_TYPE":2,"LAYOUT":{"COLORBG":"ffffff","GRADIENT_TYPE":"HORI","COLOR1":"afc928","COLOR2":"d7eb67","FORCE_SHADOW":"L","COLOR_SHADOW":"b6b8a7"}}`
- *data*: `{"DATA":{"MESSAGE":"Hello","PHONE":"0505050505"},"TYPE":"smsto"}`

So the easiest solution is probably to remove the code lines that run the URL encoding.

Comment: can you give me example to load this image, please take url and run by yourself and then give me that code

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem thank every one.

that was my url:

http://api.qrcode.unitag.fr/api?t_pwd=degraded&setting={"EYES":{"EYE_TYPE":"LLLeft","COLOR_EHD":"8a9935","COLOR_IHD":"8a9935","COLOR_EBG":"71801f","COLOR_IBG":"71801f"},"BODY_TYPE":2,"LAYOUT":{"COLORBG":"ffffff","GRADIENT_TYPE":"HORI","COLOR1":"afc928","COLOR2":"d7eb67","FORCE_SHADOW":"L","COLOR_SHADOW":"b6b8a7"}}&data={"DATA":{"MESSAGE":"Hello","PHONE":"0505050505"},"TYPE":"smsto"}

and i just added back slash before the (") (") like this  \"EYES\", and after that i use this line of code:

NSString *escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
    [img_barcode setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:nil];

and my problem is solved.